# ie.document.body.innerhtml picking up wrong HTML

Tags: vbscript, innerhtml

When I use the `innerHtml` property, it seems to be getting the HTML of the form as opposed to the forms output.  I'm after the HTML in the resulting table that contains this `f_details('277095');` where `f_details('num');` represents the license number for each agent on each row.  This script navigates to the site, makes a county selection, submits form, and dumps HTML - just not the correct HTML.  How can I target at the HTML of the resulting table (the table that appears after form submitted)?

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For i=1 To 3 '77 Counties
  If i=3 Then Exit For

  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https://lic.ok.gov/PublicPortal/OREC/FindAssociateEntity.jsp"
  Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 100: Loop

  Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 100: Loop
  IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("AddrCountyCode").Value = i

  Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 100: Loop
  For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If btn.name = "btnSearch" Then btn.Click()
  Next

  strTestString = ie.document.body.innerhtml

  filename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\License.txt"

  Set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set ts = fso.opentextfile(filename,8,true)
  ts.write strTestString
  ts.close
Next
```

The code is modified to dump only 2 pages for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you need to exit the `For Each` loop once you clicked the button.

2) you need to wait until the page finishes loading after pressing the button.

so replace you `For Each` loop with thie code:

```
For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If btn.name = "btnSearch" Then 
        btn.Click
        exit for
    End If
Next
Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 100: Loop
```

---

side notes:

you don't need to set again fso as a `FileSystemObject` in your `For i` loop since you did it already before the loop.

to set the `FileName` you don't have to create another object since you already created the `FileSystemObject` in the beginning, so set the FileName BEFORE the `For i` loop like this:

```
FileName = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\License.txt"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes!  Your comments solved my issue.  Side notes implemented.  Thank you!